# How to pass string by reference in Arduino C++

Tags: c++, arduino

I am new to Arduino, and haven't done any C++ for almost a decade. So here my really basic question:

I want to make a function that can return two strings, for that i was thinking in passing the strings by reference. Something like this:

```
void return_array_byref((char[]) & device, (char[]) & command) 
{
    device = malloc(8 * sizeof(char));
    device[0] = 'C';
    device[1] = '\n';

    command= malloc(8 * sizeof(char));
    command[0] = 'C';
    command[1] = '\n';
}

void loop() {
    char * device;
    char * command;
    return_array_byref(device, command);

    ...
}
```

I have tried using `char **`, `char[] &`, `char * &` but nothing seems to work. With the code above I am getting this:

```
arduino:6:25: error: variable or field 'return_array_byref' declared void

 void  return_array_byref((char[]) & device)

                         ^
```

What is the right way of doing this in C++?

***[EDIT][SOLUTION]***

This is the code I was looking for. I arrived to this solution based on the the answer provided bellow, so the credit goes to @Doncho :)

```
void return_array_byref(char * * device) 
{

  *device = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 8); // allocate the size of the pointer array

   (*device)[0] = 'A';
   (*device)[1] = 'B';
   (*device)[2] = 'C';
   (*device)[3] = '\n'; // this is just a new line, does not end the string
   (*device)[4] = '\0'; // null terminator is important!
}

void main() 
{
  char * string;
  return_array_byref(&string);

  cout << string << endl; 

  free(string);
}
```

Comment: I think you want `char*& device` though I'm slightly confused by your syntax

Comment: This isn't C++, it's just plain C. In `loop` you're passing the *value* of string, and not its address.
Try this instead: `return_array_byref(&string);`

I would turn it around - allocate a buffer in `loop` and pass its address to the function.

 `char buffer[10];`
 
Then the declaration of your function is just:

 `void return_Array_byref(char *buf)`

Simpler for me to understand. Better separation of who "owns" the memory.

Comment: @aMike I think you are right, my concern was that return_array_byref was going to something bigger than the size of the array. After reading your comment I think it is a better idea to pass the param and the size, and having the malloc together with the free. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid passing strings' array as a reference. Use the power of C, pass a pointer to an array, which you will dynamically allocate.

The code below does that: it receives a pointer to an array of C-strings. Then it allocates the array first (sizeof(char *) * count) elements, then it allocates each string in this array and assigns a value. If you want real C-style string, you need to terminate it with '\0', not '\n'.

I don't have my Arduino setup anymore, but the code should look like this:

```
void return_array_byref(char * * device, unsinged count) 
{
  *device = malloc(sizeof(char *)*count); // allocate the size of the pointer array
  int i;

  for(i=0; i<count; i++) {
    device[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*10); // just for the example, allocate 9 char length string

    device[i][0] = 'A'+i;
    device[i][1] = '\n'; // this is just a new line, does not end the string
    device[i][2] = '\0'; // null terminator is important!
  }  
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {

  char ** string; // bear in mind this is just ONE string, not two
  return_array_byref_string(string);

  // bear in mind, somewhere in your code you need to free up the memory!
  // free up each of the strings:
  // for(int i=0; i<count; i++) free(string[i]); // free up the strings allocation
  // free(string); // free up the strigs array array
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Doncho! I edited my question, because it was not clear. I know in advance how many strings I want to pass by reference, it is not an array of strings. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, @CarlosGarcia, I'm glad I was able to help.

Was the actual problem in the null terminator? :)